# Android - заменить кнопку

Tags: android, android-studio

Есть обработчик нажатий с вызовом метода, кнопка.
Нужно, чтобы при нажатии - вызывался метод первой кнопки (это есть), а кнопка меняла вид и анимировалась, ожидая повторного нажатия. Вероятно, надо будет вызывать другую кнопку поверх. После нажатия анимированной кнопки - вызывается второй метод, и кнопка снова становится прежней.
Я только начал в этом разбираться. Подскажете что-то?

Comment: а как именно кнопка должна менять вид и как анимировать?

Comment: Ну скажем, меняется цвет и начинают небольшие круги вокруг нее идти, типа она активирована.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У каждой кнопки в Android есть свои параметры, к которым можно обращаться из кода. Там можно менять задний фон, текст кнопки и тд. Могу посоветовать этот [сайт](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/).

Answer (score 1):

Пишите стили для кнопок..Это xml файлы в drawable.Вот тоже хорошая статья для этого https://habrahabr.ru/post/206012/

Comment: Благодарю. А в стиле одной кнопке можно задать такое поведение? Типа как переключатель + разные методы при разных состояниях.

Comment: Для этого наверное нужно написать свою кнопку.унаследоваться от view и что то там делать.

Comment: А вообще можно сделать проще.в один контейнер 2 кнопки.у одного visibility GONE у первого visible.при нажатии на первую второй visibility VISIBLE а у первого GONE.т.е.жанглировать.я часто так делал.

Comment: Благодарю, я использовал подход со State. Меняю состояния кнопки.